# Unable to execute Angular CLI commands in Visual Studio Code terminal

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I'm unable to execute `Angular CLI` commands in Visual Studio Code terminal.
When I type `ng --version` in the terminal, it is opening the ng file instead of executing the command.

Any idea of how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Have you installed @angular/cli ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed angular cli globally, npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 21):

I got the following error message while executing ng serve from VSCode:

> File C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system...

Solution:

I was able to solve the issue by running the following command in PowerShell:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

Make sure to run PowerShell with admin privileges. More on this solution can be read [here](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error in Windows. what I did is I set Command Prompt as the default shell Instead of PowerShell (PowerShell is default) in the terminal window where you select a terminal instance

Answer (score 4):

The effective solution is

1. opening the microsoft studio code by run as administrator
2. set-executionpolicy remotesigned
3. ng serve

It worked successfully.

Answer (score 3):

When you open a new terminal in VS Code, in the top right corner you are given a couple option icons:
[image]

Click on the dropdown icon and you get a couple options to choose from:

- Powershell (default)
- Command Prompt
- Git Bash
- JavaScript Debug Terminal

There is also a "Configure Terminal Settings" which allows you to change the default terminal window

Comment: This is the easiest and most accurate answer

Answer (score 1):

**my case working fine  this command**
please open power shell

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned -Scope CurrentUse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `npm install` inside your project directory and then try for `ng --version`.

Comment: I have tried creating the project in command prompt using ng new command like                               ng new test-proj. after that from visual studio code I opened the above folder and next in terminal, I ran the command npm install, it executed well. after that I ran the command ng --version, then instead of executing the ng command, it is opening the ng file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with your question but try using **Angular-CLI commands runner inside VS Code** extension in your VS Code. Works very smooth for me.

Answer (score 0):

Type `npm start` instead of `ng serve`.

Comment: Please do mention what is the reason to do such a change

Answer (score 0):

I too faced to this problem. And

- I solved the problem when starting the angular server by using `npm start` instead of `ng serve` I think the reason for this is, angular's dev server is webpack. And on default webpack works on development mode with `npm start`
- But above way didn't work for me when executing other angular-cli commands on vs-code terminal.
- So I went to the documentation of vs-code (mentioned below on recourses section)
- Initially they ask to check the execution policy by executing `Get-ExecutionPolicy` on power shell of vs-code -> I got **Restricted**
- Next `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` to get all of the execution policies with their scorps. And I got the follwing result :/

> MachinePolicy       Undefined
> Process       Undefined
> CurrentUser       Undefined
> LocalMachine       Undefined

- Then I rechecked the error which was displayed at the beginning, in vs-code power shell

  'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy
  execution policy for the current user, run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".
- In there too it's mentioned the err is about the current-user
- So I execute
  `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
- And it worked for me. It's pleasure if this would work to you too thanks.

Recourses: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.2

Answer (score 0):

ng serve comand opens an editor instead of loading local URL Issue

Solution:
This is the terminal editor on the 'ng' alias. Uninstall it with:

```
Command: sudo apt purge ng-common ng-latin
```

Then install Angular CLI (assuming you have npm installed) with
Command: sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

After that  You can use all ng commands